# Integration with putty & Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, putty

I tried to setup up openssh-server with Ubuntu 18.04,

Using Windows10 as my main machine.
Using Linux-ubuntu-18.04 on virtualbox.

> A. installed openssh-server. B. service is running. C. Tried to setup
>   a connection with putty from my windows machine -> which let to errors
>   of timeout or connection refused.

Opened sshd_config -> changed port to 12345 which didn't quite help.

any ideas ?

Thanks :>

Comment: What is the network adapter settings for your virtualbox VM? NAT or bridged? Any firewall on Ubuntu?

Comment: nope, fwd/ufw is down as well umm and I have NAT.

Comment: NAT requires port forwarding to connect from the host to guest. Did you set this up?

Comment: Okay I love you ! Changed to bridged and worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following table from the [Virtualbox online manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#table-networking-modes) shows the type of connections allowed between host, guest and internet/LAN based on the network adapter settings you choose (NAT is set by default):

[image: overview of network modes]

Since you had the network adapter set to NAT, you would need to setup port forwarding to be able to connect from the host to guest.

An alternative and easier method is to set the network adapter setting to Bridged, which puts it on the same network as the host, and allows you to connect with no further configuration.